# How to fix the text inside a block below an image

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to work on a new section for my website, but I've been having a lot of trouble when trying to keep things aligned in the way I want them too

[I've edited a screencap really quick to show what I'm trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFvcO.png)

And without text, the images line up just fine, but the moment I add text is when everything falls apart

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhBO7.png)

How can I get the results I want?

Here's my CSS code

```
 .downloadscontainer {
  text-align: center;
  }

 .downloadbutton {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  }

 .downloadbutton2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  }

 .downloadbutton3 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
  }
```

And here's the HTML code for the section I'm having trouble with

```
<div class="downloadscontainer">
<a href="https://mega.nz/file/z6ZzGSAQ#NzUXO0iZ_4ftp9YKnYBptFq5PHG7IYke6QhZ5WskMjE" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/TerminusFont.png" class="downloadbutton"></a>
<p>This is supposed to be an example</p>

<a href="https://mega.nz/file/C6ZlWZZb#5JGq04jfIP-xGz_xQ-EhpRHA7htTTcg9Pgrp_bqSqw0" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/VisitorFont.png" class="downloadbutton2"></a>
<p>This is also an example</p>

<a href="https://mega.nz/file/CyQFzYKa#Hq7uDGnrni0ZteWg-8s_-8nbAkSJjA1gZIDVcP786Ns" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/JBlackFont.png" class="downloadbutton3"></a>
<p>Another example LOL</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the .downloadscontainer a `flex` element (flex is awesome).
Then wrap each set of image+text in a div.

CSS:

```
.downloadscontainer {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

div.wrapper {
    flex: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="downloadscontainer">
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/z6ZzGSAQ#NzUXO0iZ_4ftp9YKnYBptFq5PHG7IYke6QhZ5WskMjE" target="_blank">
    <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/TerminusFont.png" class="downloadbutton"></a>
    <p>This is supposed to be an example</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/C6ZlWZZb#5JGq04jfIP-xGz_xQ-EhpRHA7htTTcg9Pgrp_bqSqw0" target="_blank">
    <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/VisitorFont.png" class="downloadbutton2"></a>
    <p>This is also an example</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/CyQFzYKa#Hq7uDGnrni0ZteWg-8s_-8nbAkSJjA1gZIDVcP786Ns" target="_blank">
    <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/JBlackFont.png" class="downloadbutton3"></a>
    <p>Another example LOL</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use margin

```
.downloadscontainer {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML:

```
<div class="downloadscontainer">
  <div>
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/z6ZzGSAQ#NzUXO0iZ_4ftp9YKnYBptFq5PHG7IYke6QhZ5WskMjE" target="_blank">
      <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/TerminusFont.png" class="downloadbutton">
    </a>
    <p>This is supposed to be an example</p>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/C6ZlWZZb#5JGq04jfIP-xGz_xQ-EhpRHA7htTTcg9Pgrp_bqSqw0" target="_blank">
      <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/VisitorFont.png" class="downloadbutton2">
    </a>
    <p>This is also an example</p>
  </div>
    
  <div>
    <a href="https://mega.nz/file/CyQFzYKa#Hq7uDGnrni0ZteWg-8s_-8nbAkSJjA1gZIDVcP786Ns" target="_blank">
      <img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/JBlackFont.png" class="downloadbutton3">
     </a>
     <p>Another example LOL</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .downloadscontainer {
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-flex;
    }
    
    .downloadscontainer > div {
      margin: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Your code got me very close to what I wanted, although for some reason the elements didn't want to align properly, that is until I attempted Richard Henage's method

Still, your help was greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to see your pictures from your code, makes it hard to help you out as I wanted.

But here's a little help:

**CSS:**

```
  .downloadscontainer {
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  }

 .downloadbutton {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  }

 .downloadbutton2 {
  display: block;
  float: center;
  }

 .downloadbutton3 {
  display: block;
  float: center;
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="downloadscontainer">
<a href="https://mega.nz/file/z6ZzGSAQ#NzUXO0iZ_4ftp9YKnYBptFq5PHG7IYke6QhZ5WskMjE" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/TerminusFont.png" class="downloadbutton"></a>
<p>This is supposed to be an example</p>

<a href="https://mega.nz/file/C6ZlWZZb#5JGq04jfIP-xGz_xQ-EhpRHA7htTTcg9Pgrp_bqSqw0" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/VisitorFont.png" class="downloadbutton2"></a>
<p>This is also an example</p>

<a href="https://mega.nz/file/CyQFzYKa#Hq7uDGnrni0ZteWg-8s_-8nbAkSJjA1gZIDVcP786Ns" target="_blank">
<img src="../../downloads/fonts/images/JBlackFont.png" class="downloadbutton3"></a>
<p>Another example LOL</p>
</div>
```

This should keep the images horizontally and the text below the images.
But keep an eye on this website, if you want to wrap the text in an image and align the text different, I think float:none; or text-align:center; is what you want to achieve:
https://hostpapasupport.com/align-float-images-website/

W3schools has many tutorials and awesome gimmicks to help you out with this matter,

so many code-snippets that could help you out with that too.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/default.asp

I hope I could help you with the sites and the code.

Comment: I got my solution yesterday, but I sincerely appreciate your help aswell

I've been following w3schools for a while now, but I often forget to look at into from time to time, thanks for the reminder!